# Cloud app to handle grocery list over Android/iPhone & Windows/Mac

Tags: ios, cloud

I am looking for an app or service that would let two different users view & update a shared shopping list from an Android phone (Galaxy Nexus running 4.1), iPhone 4S and laptops (Windows and Mac).

I was originally planning on using a text file via Dropbox, but I don't think that can be updated on the iPhone (maybe I am wrong).

Any other ideas?

Comment: "I'm looking for an app that does X" questions are not a good fit for this site. Please review the [FAQ].

Comment: That said there are dozens of ways to accomplish this. A shared document on Google Drive, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Drive](http://drive.google.com) (née Google Docs).

Just create a simple document. There's a Google Drive app for Android, of course, but even without the mobile web version works pretty well (which I'd expect you'd use with the iPhone). Windows and Mac can use the desktop browser version of the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new task list just for groceries in your google account at [calendar.google.com](https://calendar.google.com).

There are several apps that will sync the google tasks on android and iPhone.

One downside is that each device must be logged in to the same google account. They don't have a way (yet) to share task lists.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Astrid](http://astrid.com/). Its native app is available for both Android and iOS. You can access your to-do list on PC/Mac using web.

Collaborative sharing is allowed with unlimited no. of users. Users can also  leave notes on tasks for other users.

Answer (score 0):

There are about one bazillion apps like this.  I've got a (somewhat outdated) list at [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ahaw8dCqimf8dDN6NEg5YTF1SnNTZndfUjlsZzhGRHc).